# Apache POI Update Excel File After Adding Columns/Rows to JTable

Tags: java, swing, apache-poi

New here so please be kind.  I've spent a few hours trawling through posts trying to find an answer but no such luck.

I have an excel file that I import into a JTable and can then edit.  Add columns, rows etc.

When I click the button to add a column or row they appear on the JTable as expected.  However when I click the save button to save the file it hasn't added the new columns or rows to the Excel file.
I thought my save wasn't working correctly, but if I edit one of the two columns I already have saved in the Excel file the changes are saved to the Excel file so I am confused as to why I can edit the existing data in the file but any new rows or columns are not saved.

My export to excel is:

```
public void toExcel()
    {
    try 
        {

        FileInputStream fsIP = new FileInputStream(new File("Recipes.xls"));
        HSSFWorkbook fWorkbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fsIP);
        HSSFSheet fSheet = fWorkbook.getSheet("RECIPES");
        HSSFFont sheetTitleFont = fWorkbook.createFont();
        HSSFCellStyle cellStyle = fWorkbook.createCellStyle();
        sheetTitleFont.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        TableColumnModel tcm = tables.getColumnModel();




        HSSFRow fRow = fSheet.createRow((short) 0);
        for(int j = 0; j < tcm.getColumnCount(); j++) 
            {
                HSSFCell cell = fRow.createCell((int) j);
                cell.setCellValue(tcm.getColumn(j).getHeaderValue().toString());
            }
        for (int i = 0, row = 1; i < models.getRowCount(); i++, row++) 
            {
                HSSFRow fRow1 = fSheet.createRow((short) row);
                for (int j = 0; j < models.getColumnCount(); j++) 
                    {
                        HSSFCell cell = fRow1.createCell((int) j);
                        cell.setCellValue(models.getValueAt(i, j).toString());
                        cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
                    }
            }

        FileOutputStream output_file = new FileOutputStream(new File("Recipes.xls"));
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(output_file);
        fWorkbook.write(output_file);
        fWorkbook.close();
        bos.close();
        output_file.close();
        }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
        null, "Changes Saved",
        "Confirmation",
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

My method for adding a column is as follows:

```
public void addNewRecipe()
{

    models.addColumn(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter A Description for Recipe"));


}
```

Thanks.

EDIT

Here is code for calling toExcel

```
saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        { 
            @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
                {         
                    { 

                        models = new DefaultTableModel(datas, headers); 
                         tableWidth = models.getColumnCount() * 150; 
                         tableHeight = models.getRowCount() * 50; 
                         tables.setPreferredSize(new Dimension( tableWidth, tableHeight));
                         tables.setModel(models); 
                         tables.setRowHeight(50);


                        toExcel(); 

                    } 
                } 
        });
```

Comment: Please show code where you are calling `toExcel`

Comment: Thank you for responding.  Now added code.